# TSQL using EXISTS returns more records than expected

Tags: t-sql, exists

There is something wrong with the query or my understanding of how exists should work.

I want to return a list of duplicates by id to isolate and eliminate.

The query:

```
select id
     , ref_id
from assets
where exists
(
    select ref_id
    from assets
    where ref_id is not null
    group by ref_id
    having count(id)>1
)
```

The subquery returns exactly what I am expecting, but the entire query returns ALL assets records.  I think it should only include that in the subquery.

Please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a field from the outer table inside the exists:

```
select id
     , ref_id
from assets _assets
where exists
(
    select ref_id
    from assets _existingAssets
    where ref_id is not null
    and _existingAssets.ref_id = _assets.ref_id
    group by ref_id
    having count(id)>1
)
```

You could also do this with an `in` caluse:

```
select id
     , ref_id
from assets
where ref_id in
(
    select ref_id
    from assets
    where ref_id is not null
    group by ref_id
    having count(id)>1
)
```

Comment: Is the field `ref_id` not in both?  I'm pretty sure it is.

Comment: This is the line you are missing `and _existingAssets.ref_id = _assets.ref_id`. You need to define a relationship for the exists.

Comment: That is a table alias for the assets table inside the exists clause.

Comment: Without defining the relationship you could change the query to `Exists (select 1)` and it would return the same result. See example B here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx

Comment: I'll give you the answer because of the `in` answer.  That's what I was looking for - thank you!  Still not sure the point of `exists` if you have to do all that work for it in the first place?

Comment: In this case I would not use the `exists` clause myself.